# print the selected area in a web page of laravel through javascript or css

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel, media-queries

i have a page of reporting which contents navs headers and footers now i want to print the table and 4 fields which i put in a same div named printme

```
<div id="printme">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                        <label for="report_type">Type</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="report_type" id="report_type">
                                <option value="">Report Type</option>
                                <option value="product wise">Product Wise</option>
                                <option value="salesman wise">Salesman Wise</option>
                                <option value="orderbooker wise">OrderBooker Wise</option>
                                <option value="vendor wise">Vendor Wise</option>
                                <option value="client wise">Client Wise</option>

                            </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                        <label for="resource_name">Resource Name</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="resource_name" id="resource_name">
                                <option value="">Name
                                </option>
                            </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                        <label for="from_date">From Date</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="date" placeholder="From Date" name="from_date" id="from_date" /required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                        <label for="to_date">To Date</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="date" placeholder="To Date" name="to_date" id="to_date" /required>
                    </div>
            <!-- /.row-->
                </div>
                <div>
                    <table class="table table-responsive-sm table-bordered table-striped table-sm" id="report_table">
                        <thead id="head">
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="body">
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

its javascript code is here

```
function printDiv(divName){
var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

window.print();

document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
```

}

this function triggers on a button but doing with this method it erases the data of four fields at the top

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="printDiv('printme')"> Print Report</button>
```

i only want the print of Report Type
Resource Name
from Date
To date[full page

also tried this through CSS but is not working

```
#printme {
display: none;
}
@media print {
.no-printme  {
    display: none;
}
 #printme  {
    display: block;
}
```

}

anyone please help to print the table and four fields at the top in a page

Answer (score 0):

just come to a solution that laravel has its on style.css file in view/css go there and find @media print you will get

```
@media print {
 .d-print-none {
display: none !important;}
 .d-print-inline {
display: inline !important;}

 .d-print-inline-block {
display: inline-block !important;}

 .d-print-block {
display: block !important;}

 .d-print-table {
display: table !important;}

 .d-print-table-row {
display: table-row !important;}

 .d-print-table-cell {
display: table-cell !important;}

 .d-print-flex 
display: -ms-flexbox !important;
display: flex !important; }

 .d-print-inline-flex {
display: -ms-inline-flexbox !important;
display: inline-flex !important;}}
```

now hide the elements by using `class ="d-print-none"` in tag attributes and you are done
other `d-print` options are also available for display in print you can try it